# Application not compatible with older Android versions

Tags: java, android, gluon-mobile

I'm generating an Android application via `mvn -Pandroid gluonfx:build gluonfx:package`. Here are the versions from the POM:

```
        <maven-compiler-plugin-version>3.10.1</maven-compiler-plugin-version>
        <maven-surefire-plugin-version>3.0.0-M6</maven-surefire-plugin-version>
        <javafx-maven-plugin-version>0.0.8</javafx-maven-plugin-version>
        <gluonfx-maven-plugin-version>1.0.14</gluonfx-maven-plugin-version>

        <java-version>17</java-version>
        <javafx-version>18.0.1</javafx-version>
        <charm-version>6.1.0</charm-version>
        <attach-version>4.0.15</attach-version>
```

Using graalvm-svm-java17-linux-gluon-22.1.0.1-Final

The application works well on Android 8. However, when trying to install it on Android 7.0, a message pops up saying that the application is not compatible with the device. I'm not sure where the default version is specified, but following the [instructions](https://docs.gluonhq.com/#platforms_android_distribution_manifest), I copied the manifest file, which was

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<manifest xmlns:android='http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android' package='my.app.demo' android:versionCode='1' android:versionName='1.0'>
    <supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    
    <application android:label='MyApp' android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name='com.gluonhq.helloandroid.MainActivity' android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
             <intent-filter>
                <category android:name='android.intent.category.LAUNCHER'/>
                <action android:name='android.intent.action.MAIN'/>
             </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name='com.gluonhq.helloandroid.PermissionRequestActivity'/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

and added a line for supporting sdk 24 ([matches](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platforms#7.0) Android 7.0):

```
    ...
    <supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="24" android:targetSdkVersion="24"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    ...
```

Then I put it in my project under `src/android/AndroidManifest.xml` and ran `mvn -Pandroid gluonfx:build gluonfx:package` again. The APK was generated successfully, but upon installation the same error message appeared.

How do I install the app on Android 7.0?

Comment: Do all your dependencies support an sdk version that low?  Also, targetSdkVersion 24 won't be allowed on the Play store.  Their minimum target sdk is 31 for new apps, 30 for updates (which becomes 31 in November) and they bump this annually.

Comment: `application is not compatible with the device` could mean that your device has 32 bits, which is [not supported](https://docs.gluonhq.com/#_platforms), because GraalVM is only for 64 bits. Can you verify that?

Comment: @JoséPereda My dependencies are rather simple: gluon mobile stuff (charm, attach, glisten), Jackson, and JavaFX. For now, I'm installing the apk directly on the device, I'll worry about the play store later. The device doesn't show if it's 32 or 64 bits, the info it gives is kernel version 3.18.35 and ARMv7 processor rev 4 (v71).

Comment: ARMv7 is 32 bits. If you check the generated APK file, it has ARMv8 libraries only (64bits).

Comment: @JoséPereda I see, so in general, all Gluon Mobile applications I create are for 64 bits only? I should alerts the potential users if that's the case.

Comment: Yes, the JavaFX/Gluon Mobile applications leverage GraalVM, via GluonFX plugin, to create native images, but it has only 64 bits support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the device uses an ARMv7 processor, which uses a 32bit architecture. GraalVM supports only 64 bits, so the APKs produced by it will work only on devices with 64bits, like those with ARMv8.